# setTaskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock in AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Anybody know how to handle authentication in the 2.0 version of AFNetworking?  I tried the below without success.  The block is getting called (I had an NSLog in there) but the response is still a 401 error

```
[self setTaskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionTask *task, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge, NSURLCredential *__autoreleasing *credential) {
    *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    return NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
}];
```

Comment: Just curious, have you tried setting the `credential` property on your AFHTTPRequestOperation object?

Comment: I'm subclassing AFHTTPClient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a bug in AFNetworking 2.0.  Here is the implementation:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
    NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
    __block NSURLCredential *credential = nil;

    if (self.taskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge) {
        disposition = self.taskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(session, task, challenge, &credential);
    } else {
        [self URLSession:session didReceiveChallenge:challenge completionHandler:completionHandler];
        return;
    }

    if (completionHandler) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, credential);
    }
}
```

Note that even though you're specifying `NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential`, AFNetworking is passing back `NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling`, which states "Default handling for the challenge - as if this delegate were not implemented; the credential parameter is ignored."

Comment: I opened a pull request to resolve the issue.  I don't have a server to check this against, but feel free to check out the code and let me know if it works now: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1252

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  I changed the source to pass in disposition to the completionHandler and now it's working perfectly.  thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

Override the method given,

```
override func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))

}
```