# AFNetworking upload task with credentials (HTTP Basic Auth)

Tags: objective-c, upload, afnetworking-2, basic-authentication

I need to upload video files from my app to a server. I tried doing so via `[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager post:parameters:success:failure]` but unfortunately kept getting request timeouts. I'm now trying something similar to *Creating an Upload Task* from [the AF Docs](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

I read [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424408/settaskdidreceiveauthenticationchallengeblock-in-afnetworking-2-0) and the [AF Docs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.1/Classes/AFURLSessionManager.html#//api/name/setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:) about `setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:` and tried to implement the whole upload malarky as follows:

```
__block ApiManager *myself = self;

// Construct the URL
NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", defaultUrl, [self getPathForEndpoint:endpoint]];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Build a session manager
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

// Set authentication handler
[manager setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition(NSURLSession *session, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge, NSURLCredential *__autoreleasing *credential) {
    *credential = myself.credentials;
    return NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
}];


// Create the upload task
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:filePath progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        [myself endpoint:endpoint returnedFailure:error];
    } else {
        [myself endpoint:endpoint returnedSuccess:responseObject];
    }
}];

// and run with it
[uploadTask resume];
```

The `myself.credentials` object has been set previously to have the correct username and password. Whenever this request fires, I get `401 unauthorised` as a response. I tried putting `NSLog(@"CHALLENGE")` inside the challenge block above, but it never seems to get called, so AFNetworking isn't giving me a way to supply credentials. I know that this works perfectly well on the server side because I've tested it with Postman.

How can I get AFNetworking to let me supply credentials for HTTP Basic Auth with this upload task?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about AFNetworking's `setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock`, but as long as you have an `NSMutableURLRequest` you may set the Authorization HTTP Header directly on the request object:

`[request setValue:base64AuthorizationString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];`

Keep in mind that the value must be base64 representation of the `username:password` string.

Otherwise, for GET, POST, etc. requests on a session manager, you may set the credentials on the request serializer used by the session manager. See:

`[AFHTTPRequestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:password:]`
`[AFHTTPRequestSerializer clearAuthorizationHeader]`